# js number function for calculator error

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain to me why I get the error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` when I run the below function.

```
function number(a){
    var last = parseInt(stream.charAt(stream.length-1));
    if(stream === ''){
      stream = a;
    }
    else if(isNumber(last)){
      console.log(last);
      stream.charAt(stream.length-1) = last*10 + a;
    }
    else{
      stream += ' '+a;

    }
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = stream;
}
```

Comment: `stream` is `undefined`

Comment: `var stream` add in your javascript

Comment: `stream` could very well be a global, guys. That's not the issue here.

Comment: Alice, what __exactly__ is the `stream.charAt(stream.length-1)` supposed to do?

Comment: 'stream' is indeed a global variable. I am trying to debug some JavaScript calculator code that doesn't work.

The code is part of a bigger function:

`function number(a){
    var last = parseInt(stream.charAt(stream.length-1));
    if(stream === ''){
      stream = a;
    }
    else if(isNumber(last)){
      console.log(last);
      stream += '0' + a;
    }
    else{
      stream += ' '+a;

    }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
stream.charAt(stream.length-1) = last*10 + a;
```

You can't assign something to `stream.charAt()`. That function only returns a character.

From what I can gather, you're getting the last character from the `stream`. If it's a integer, you multiply it by `10`, then append `a` to the stream.

Instead of that, this will give the same result:

```
stream += '0' + a;
```

Since you're adding the value back into the array, it really doesn't matter if you multiply a single digit integer with `10`, or if you just add a `"0"` after it.

Comment: Experience speaks

Comment: thank you @Cerbrus, it's now working, appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be this codepart

```
stream.charAt(stream.length-1) = last*10 + a;
```

charAt returns a string, and not a position in your stream (i assume that your stream is a string), so you cant overwrite it.

To solve this you could do something like:

```
 stream = stream.substring(0,stream.length-1)+last*10+a
```

Im not allowed to comment but Cerbrus answer wont work for last = '0' and will in this case add an additional 0, this should work

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that you can't assign like this

```
 stream.charAt(stream.length-1) = last*10 + a;
```

Comment: 1 correct answer is enough. No need to duplicate it. :)

Comment: was just trying to help sir